# uBlock Origin, change CSS Top position of an element

Tags: html, css, adblock

for this website (https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__346.html) I am trying to move the main text in the middle, up to the top. `<div id="content_blaettern_12793">`

It has a fixed position via the css:

```
#content_blaettern_12793 {
position: absolute;
top: 205px;
right: 50px;
left: 15em; 
}
```

Now, in uBlock Origin I tried

```
www.gesetze-im-internet.de##content_blaettern_12793:style(top: 0px !important;)
```

However, this has no effect.

Anyone can help me out, how to achieve this?
My end goal would be to remove the blue bar at the top and the logo in the top left, and just show the middle text container in the top left.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Achieve Your Goal With This

```
#fTop{
   display:none!important;
}
#fTopLogos{
   display:none!important;
}
#content_blaettern_12793{
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 50px;
  left: -230px;
}
#blaettercontainer_12793{
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  left: -220px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: hey, really appreciate your help. However, how do I do this as a rule in uBlock Origin (as an entry in uBlock Settings>My Filters) ?
Or: How do I make it, that the css code you posted overwrites the original one, everytime I load the webpage. Thank you!